# Caps Lock Key freezes JavaFX application thread

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx-2, javafx, ubuntu-12.04

When I run any JavaFX code (even the hello world http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm) and I press the capslock key, the application freezes until I turn caps lock off.

I'm running JavaFX in Kubuntu 12.04, maybe it's a kubuntu's bug, I didn't had the chance to try on another operating system.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you try on different browsers (if you are running the example on a Browser)?  Or different JRE versions?

Comment: That's weird, I advise [filing a bug](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com) against the JavaFX runtime project which includes a complete description of your environment.  Note that I tried a JavaFX app on a 2012 Macbook Air OS X 10.8 and it did not freeze when caps lock was on.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the bug was fixed on version 2.2.6 http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-27502